# Selecting values on click of button if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<div class="tbs_icontainer" style="height: 415px;">
<TABLE class=tbs_table cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
<THEAD class=tbs_head>
</THEAD>
<TBODY class=tbs_body>
<TR style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff" class=tbs_tr jQuery1368094469282="11">
<TD style="WIDTH: 20px" class=tbs_td><INPUT class=search value=0 type=checkbox name=search jQuery1368094469282="12"></TD>
**<TD class=tbs_td>00-0227101-</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>1</TD>**
<TD class=tbs_td>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>Medak</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>02/27/2013</TD>
<TD style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" class=tbs_td>02/01/2013</TD></TR>
<TR style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ebf4fa" class=tbs_tr jQuery1368094469282="13">
<TD style="WIDTH: 20px" class=tbs_td><INPUT class=search value=1 type=checkbox name=search jQuery1368094469282="14"></TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>01-123456789-</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>1</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>2010 Acura CSX 4D Sed</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>Insured Ln, Insured Firstname</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>03/05/2013</TD>
<TD style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" class=tbs_td>03/05/2013</TD></TR>
<TR style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ebf4fa" class=tbs_tr jQuery1368094469282="17">
<TD style="WIDTH: 20px" class=tbs_td><INPUT class=search value=3 type=checkbox name=search jQuery1368094469282="18"></TD>
**<TD class=tbs_td>01-4444445-</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>1</TD>**
<TD class=tbs_td>2012 Acura RL 4D Sed</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>Insured Last Name, Insured First Name</TD>
<TD class=tbs_td>03/06/2013</TD>
<TD style="BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" class=tbs_td>03/06/2013</TD></TR>
```

In the above DIV,I have a requirement that on click of button i have to select the values of first two TDs(highlighted in bold) only if chechbox is checked.I am not getting a way how to do this?

On Click of button i am calling a jquery method :-

```
     <fw:Button runat="server" ID="btnSelect" Text="Select" OnClientClick="getSelectedClaims();" />         
                                          function getSelectedClaims()
 {
            $('.tbs_table').each(function ('.search:checkbox:checked') {
               //What to do to select values from first two TDs after first TD if checkbox is checked
            });
        }
```

Comment: Care to share what you tried already?

Comment: i said i am not getting a way how to do this

Comment: It is always better to show what you found, tried. Just assumming you  used a search engine to see if something useful came up on a "jquery select spedific td" search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.tbs_table tr').has('.search:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    var $tr = $(this);
    var val1 = $tr.find('td').eq(1).text();
    var val2 = $tr.find('td').eq(2).text();

    //do something
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3WHM5/)

Comment: Didn't realize OP wanted first 2 values after EACH TR... +1, nice

Answer (score 1):

I've solved similar problem in my online quiz engine (see demo: http://www.webinfocentral.com) like shown in the following jQuery code snippet:

```
var _rows = $(this).find('tr');
for (i = 0; i < _rows.length; i++) {
    // find out if checkbox is checked
    _checked = $(_rows[i]).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked');
}
```